# panda adding Iteratively Add Columns to a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I want to save variable node to each row , each row has different node value

//this line I want to add variable node to column UPU, but currently it only copy the latest node variable and save to all row same value.

how to make it

```
current result 

No. KP      UPU
88888888    tidak berjaya
66666666    tidak berjaya
55555555    tidak berjaya
```

```
expected result
No. KP      UPU
88888888    tidak berjaya
66666666    tahniah
55555555    harap maaf
```

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from pandas import ExcelWriter


excel_file = 'upu6.csv'
students = pd.read_csv(excel_file, dtype={'No. KP': object})
# print (students.head())
# writer = pd.ExcelWriter('outputUpu.xlsx')


options = Options()
    # options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")
options.headless = False
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver.exe', options=options) # Your webdriver path

for index,row in students.iterrows():
    nokp = (row["No. KP"])
    browser.get("https://jpt.unimas.my/semakKeputusanSPM.jsp")
    ic = browser.find_element_by_id('vNOKP')
    ic.send_keys(nokp)

    browser.find_element_by_id('bMASUK').click()

    result = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")

    for node in result.find_all(text=lambda t: t and any(x in t for x in ['TIDAK BERJAYA', 'TAHNIAH', 'HARAP MAAF. TIADA REKOD PERMOHONAN'])):
        
        print(row['No. KP'] +" "+node)
        //this line I want to add variable node to column UPU, but currently it only copy the 
        //latest node variable and save to all row
        students['UPU'] = node

    
    

students.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.at()` to locate the cell you want and change its value

first set you `No. KP` as index for the dataframe

```
students.set_index('No. KP')
```

then you can locate the cell using the index and column name

```
students.at[row['No. KP'], ['UPU']] = node
```

Comment: students.at(row['No. KP'], ['UPU']) = node
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: updated the code, sorry for the bracket typo

Comment: it update next column, but also still show dataframe on above, see this result file

[link]https://pasteimg.com/images/2021/07/30/Untitled.png

i would like it update it on second column

Comment: because right now, the index column is still the `default` one, you have to set `No. KP` as your index column for the dataframe, which can be set by `students.set_index('No. KP')`